# How to null values based on an other field value

Tags: sql, oracle

Can somebody help me how to achieve the following?

I've got the following result:

```
APP ¦ CW ¦     DT     ¦ DAY
---------------------------
SKL ¦ 05 ¦ 2017-02-03 ¦ FRI
SKL ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ MON
SKL ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-07 ¦ TUE
SKL ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-08 ¦ WED
SKL ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-09 ¦ THU
SKL ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-10 ¦ FRI
SKL ¦ 07 ¦ 2017-02-13 ¦ MON
SKL ¦ 07 ¦ 2017-02-14 ¦ TUE
XZU ¦ 05 ¦ 2017-02-03 ¦ FRI
XZU ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ MON
XZU ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-07 ¦ TUE
XZU ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-08 ¦ WED
XZU ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-09 ¦ THU
XZU ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-10 ¦ FRI
XZU ¦ 07 ¦ 2017-02-13 ¦ MON
XZU ¦ 07 ¦ 2017-02-14 ¦ TUE
WIO ¦ 05 ¦ 2017-02-03 ¦ FRI
WIO ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ MON
..
.
```

And instead of the above I would like to get this:

```
APP ¦ CW ¦     DT     ¦ DAY
---------------------------
SKL ¦    ¦ 2017-02-03 ¦ FRI
SKL ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ MON
SKL ¦    ¦ 2017-02-07 ¦ TUE
SKL ¦    ¦ 2017-02-08 ¦ WED
SKL ¦    ¦ 2017-02-09 ¦ THU
SKL ¦    ¦ 2017-02-10 ¦ FRI
SKL ¦ 07 ¦ 2017-02-13 ¦ MON
SKL ¦    ¦ 2017-02-14 ¦ TUE
XZU ¦    ¦ 2017-02-03 ¦ FRI
XZU ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ MON
XZU ¦    ¦ 2017-02-07 ¦ TUE
XZU ¦    ¦ 2017-02-08 ¦ WED
XZU ¦    ¦ 2017-02-09 ¦ THU
XZU ¦    ¦ 2017-02-10 ¦ FRI
XZU ¦ 07 ¦ 2017-02-13 ¦ MON
XZU ¦    ¦ 2017-02-14 ¦ TUE
WIO ¦    ¦ 2017-02-03 ¦ FRI
WIO ¦ 06 ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ MON
..
.
```

So I'm trying to null the "CW" column when the "DAY" is not 'MON'. This should have a simple solution, but till yet I didn't found the way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible but since this is a presentation issue better do it in your program logic

Comment: `case when DAY = 'MON' then cw end as cw`, but I agree with @juergend's comment.

Comment: @mathguy, that case expression was intended to be part of a SELECT. Not to modify table values.

Comment: Please post your query

Comment: Tnx Jürgen, this has helped me.

Comment: @jarlh - I deleted my comment because it was EXACTLY the union of Juergen's point and yours. But since you replied to my comment: I didn't mean "modify the data in the base table" - I meant "modify the data returned by the query." That is still **data** (which may be subject to further processing, either in SQL itself or in Java/C# etc.) - unless there is a guarantee of no further processing, now and in the future, one shouldn't use the `case` expression at this point. Address presentation issues in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `CASE`:

```
select APP,
    case when day = 'MON' then CW end cw,
    DT,
    DAY
from your_table;
```